# How does bond strength affect catenation?

Tags: bond

I am wondering why C with single bond strength [347 Kj/mol](http://butane.chem.uiuc.edu/cyerkes/Chem104ACSpring2009/Genchemref/bondenergies.html) is able to form much longer linear bond chain, while S with single bond strength [266 Kj/mol](http://butane.chem.uiuc.edu/cyerkes/Chem104ACSpring2009/Genchemref/bondenergies.html) is able to do so with difficulty, although not even comparable.

It might appear, and even obvious, that the longer the chain, the greater is the chance to break any segment of chain, and thus unstable.

So my question is, does the bond energy in any other way affect the catenation property.

For example, consider a chain of 3 carbons. Does the bond between C1 and C2 affect the bond between C2 and C3. Molecular Orbital Theory might say, yes. But I am not able to understand how?

Comment: There is no stable linear chain of carbon atoms with single bonds, you should consider the sp hybridization.

Comment: Difficulty? You melt sulfur, you heat it a little more, maybe to $200\ ^\circ C$, pour it in the cold water, and here you have them, the long chains of S.